# Saving image to gallery from imageview in viewpager

Tags: java, android, imageview

I managed to save the image from imageview to gallery with the onlongclicklistner() with the help of code given below. But the problem is that it always save the last image dosent matters which image i try to save.

```
public class CapturePhotoUtils {


        public final String insertImage(ContentResolver cr,
                                               Bitmap source,
                                               String title,
                                               String description) {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, title);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, title);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, description);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
            // Add the date meta data to ensure the image is added at the front of the gallery
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());

            Uri url = null;
            String stringUrl = null;    /* value to be returned */

            try {
                url = cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                if (source != null) {
                    OutputStream imageOut = cr.openOutputStream(url);
                    try {
                        source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, imageOut);
                    } finally {
                        imageOut.close();
                    }

                    long id = ContentUris.parseId(url);
                    // Wait until MINI_KIND thumbnail is generated.
                    Bitmap miniThumb = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
                    // This is for backward compatibility.
                    storeThumbnail(cr, miniThumb, id, 50F, 50F, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                } else {
                    cr.delete(url, null, null);
                    url = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (url != null) {
                    cr.delete(url, null, null);
                    url = null;
                }
            }

            if (url != null) {
                stringUrl = url.toString();
            }

            return stringUrl;
        }


        private final Bitmap storeThumbnail(
                ContentResolver cr,
                Bitmap source,
                long id,
                float width,
                float height,
                int kind) {

            // create the matrix to scale it
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

            float scaleX = width / source.getWidth();
            float scaleY = height / source.getHeight();

            matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY);

            Bitmap thumb = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0,
                    source.getWidth(),
                    source.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true
            );

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND,kind);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,(int)id);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.HEIGHT,thumb.getHeight());
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.WIDTH,thumb.getWidth());

            Uri url = cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            try {
                OutputStream thumbOut = cr.openOutputStream(url);
                thumb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, thumbOut);
                thumbOut.close();
                return thumb;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                return null;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am putting images from the viewpager getting images from array of drawables

class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.length;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_slider_item, container, false);

        imageView = (TouchImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

        imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                CapturePhotoUtils photoUtils = new CapturePhotoUtils();
                imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap b = imageView.getDrawingCache();
                photoUtils.insertImage(Full_Screen_Slider.this.getContentResolver(),
                    b, "1image", "this is downloaded image sample");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "longpress ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;
            }
        });

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

}
```

Comment: Check if the **onLongClickListener()** always returns the same data or different?  The code seems fine.

Comment: post your onLongClickListener() code

Comment: how you are putting multiple images on imgeView can you show that ? may be making imageView final can solve this issue.it will make separate object for each imageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container,final int position) {
       final View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_slider_item, container, false);

      final TouchImageView imageView = (TouchImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

        imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                CapturePhotoUtils photoUtils = new CapturePhotoUtils();
                imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap b = imageView.getDrawingCache();
                photoUtils.insertImage(Full_Screen_Slider.this.getContentResolver(),
                    b, "1image", "this is downloaded image sample");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "longpress ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;
            }
        });

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }
```

it is replacing your view each time it calls instantiateItem so make it final which will help.

Comment: just 1 quick question can you tell me where to put progress dialog in this code to show image is downloading and hide it when image is stored

Comment: try to user Glide to load image inimageview which will give you lister for Resource  Ready where you can hide your progress bar https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets